# What is the signature of a function that takes in a function pointer and returns a function pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I would like to know what is the signature of a function that takes in a function pointer and returns a function pointer?

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: Hmm, I've never been great with function pointers, but it seems to me that you would have to know what the input and output function pointer functions have as parameters and what they return to answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E.g.:

```
void (*f(void (*)(void)))(void)
```

... which is much more readably using `typedefs`:

```
typedef void (*VoidFunctionPointer)(void);
VoidFunctionPointer f(VoidFunctionPointer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be with a typedef:

```
typedef int(*int_fn_ptr)(int);

int_fn_ptr my_func(int_fn_ptr f);
```

**Disclaimer**: I can't verify that there are no typos here.

Comment: @Georg initially I thought you were wrong. Then I remembered that function pointers are weird and don't act like normal typedefs, so I rolled back my rollback. No hard feelings, you can change the last period to a smiley if you like if you'd like to "reclaim your credit" :D

Comment: Sorry and nevermind then, have seen people do weird things here "for points" :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to better define the *function pointer* taken as parameter and return type.
Anyway, here's an example with a simple function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* abs */

typedef int fx(int);

/* foo takes a function pointer and returns a function pointer */
fx *foo(fx *bar) {
  if (bar) return bar;
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  fx *(*signature)(fx *) = foo;        /* signature points to foo */
  if (signature(abs)) printf("ok\n");
  return 0;
}
```